# why this Query not return any result

Tags: sql

simply i want to update the time which employee Leaves his work

```
create proc [dbo].[upensraf]
@empl1 varchar , 
@ensraf time
as
update dbo.Elamal_elyome 
set Elanseraf=@ensraf
where  ID = (
    select (max(dbo.Elamal_elyome.ID)) 
    from dbo.Elamal_elyome  
    where employee=@empl1
)
```

Comment: The `UPDATE` command does not return any results.  What did you expect it to return?

Comment: @RBarryYoung -- I don't think the OP is asking why the query isn't returning results from an update statement, but rather why the update itself isn't working.  OP wants to update the time when employee leaves work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the size of your @empl1 varchar variable -- without defining the size, it tries to search for an employee with a single character (which would work if that's what you were trying to update).  Change the size to match what's in your table definition -- I used 100 in the sample below:

```
create proc [dbo].[upensraf]
@empl1 varchar(100) , 
@ensraf time
as
update dbo.Elamal_elyome 
set Elanseraf=@ensraf
where  ID = (
    select (max(dbo.Elamal_elyome.ID)) 
    from dbo.Elamal_elyome  
    where employee=@empl1
)
```

Here's a working [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bbd8d/1)

Comment: @MohamedEl-Raei  -- np, glad I could help!